# Android add ArrayList<Object> as a variable in Class Object

Tags: java, android, class, arraylist, xmlpullparser

I have two classes, one is a `Question` and the other `Choices`. Some fields are as follows:

`Question`:

```
public String id;
public String text;
public String image;
public ArrayList<Choices> choices;
```

`Choices`:

```
boolean isCorrect;
String choice;
```

Put simply, I get some XML and parse it. There are Questions and to associate the 3, 4, or 5 answers that may be with a questions, I make an `ArrayList<Choices>` of all choices (or answers) and then `set` it into the Question class. But I try to read the list in a particular object, and it returns nothing.

Here's the code where I do the final combinations and testing:

```
question.setChoices(choiceList);
//Log.d("demo", ">>>" + question.getChoices());
questionList.add(question);
question = null;
choices = null;
choiceList.clear();
```

(LONGER VERSION)

```
... // other parsing code before this

case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

            if (parser.getName().equals("question")) {

                // Testing purposes
                //Log.d("demo", ">>>" + choiceList.toString());
                question.setChoices(choiceList);
                //Log.d("demo", ">>>" + question.getChoices());
                questionList.add(question);
                question = null;
                choices = null;
                choiceList.clear();
                Log.d("demo", ">>>" + questionList.get(0).getChoices());

            }

            break;

        default:
            break;

        } // END Switch

        event = parser.next();

    } // END While loop

    return questionList;

}

}
```

Basically, I look at the log and I can print all data in the `Question` object except for the `ArrayList<Choices>` information. All I get is `[]`. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this.

EDITED EXTRA INFO

```
else if (parser.getName().equals("choice")) {

                boolean isCorrect;
                String answer;

                if (parser.getAttributeValue(null, "answer") != null) {
                    isCorrect = true;
                    answer = parser.nextText();
                    choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                }
                else {
                    isCorrect = false;
                    answer = parser.nextText();
                    choices = new Choices(isCorrect, answer);
                }

                choiceList.add(choices);

            } // END Choices Parsing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

choicesList.clear will actually delete all data from the list.  Since the list is the same one as in the question object, the one in the question object gets cleared too.  Instead of clearing it, you want to create a new ArrayList.

Comment: I edited my original post. As you can see, I do choices = new Choices(). That's a great revelation you had, now I'm trying to determine how to implement it. Because the entire while loop reads through, line by line of XML. I guess my question is, do I need to make a new least each time with a new "name" per say?